# Android : How to record a live stream video using ExoPlayer lib

Tags: android, live-streaming, recording, exoplayer

I'm using ExoPlayer lib and i need to record the live stream video and save it directly into SD card.

This is what I have so far:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();


mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(???????);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(???????);


mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
```

any help

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried already?

Comment: I used MediaRecorder but i didn't know its true or not

Comment: I want to use this tutorial but i need to replace the Mobile Cam Source with the source which coming from the ExoPlayer
http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/android-video-capture-tutorial.html